# Why is my Facebook graph session being returned as null

Tags: facebook, graph

The login button shows up fine

I can login and give the app permissions

But when the page reload happens (using the javascript sdk) the session value from the facebook object is NULL.

I've wasted 4 days on trying to solve this problem...and I have the answer.  I'm self posting because nobody should have to suffer through that crap for such a silly problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your connect url on the facebook developer page is at the root of the url you are redirecting to.  For example

connect url is www.$#@%.com
if you do a window.location='http://$#@%.com';

You're going to be so SOL.

make sure sure sure (for the love of god) it looks like 
window.location='http://www.$#@%.com';

I hope I've saved someone 4 days of pain.